# Ошибка Connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java, исключения, чат

Написан простенький чат на Java. Серверная часть стартует, клиентская выдает ошибку:

> Connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Пересмотрел все - результата нет, [ссылка на GitHub](https://github.com/Zvezd/Chat.git)

Comment: Клиент и сервер запускаются на одном компьютере?

Comment: Да, на одном. Все запускается из Идеи.

Comment: Что, никто не вкурсе?